# NameError when inputting y/n prompt to end loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nameerror

I am attempting to write a simple Letter Grade Converter that takes an input from 0-100 and returns a letter grade. The End of the while statement asks for a y/n input to continue the conversion or end it. Entering Y seems to always return a name error that y has not been defined.

```
print("Letter Grade Converter")

choice = "y"
while choice.lower() == "y":
    number = int(input("Enter numerical grade: "))
    if number > 87:
        letter = "A"
    elif number > 79:
        letter = "B"
    elif number > 66:
        letter = "C"
    elif number > 59:
        letter = "D"
    else:
        letter = "F"

    print("Letter Grade: " + letter)
    choice = input("Continue (y/n)?: ")
print ("Bye!")
```

I have already defined choice in the beginning, is that what is causing a name error??

Comment: So what's the full traceback for the error?

Comment: And is this Python 2 perhaps?

Comment: It is python 2.7 i believe

Comment: The traceback is: File "C:\PythonPrograms\Grade.py", line 3, in <module> while choice.lower() == "y":   NameError: name "choice" is not defined

Comment: The name error you are getting can’t actually be caused by the code posted; that would only happen if the `choice = "y"` line before it was missing. Note the line number, in the code posted here your `while` is on line 4 instead.